# Matener información en formularios

Tags: html, c#, asp.net

No puedo mantener el valor seleccionado tanto en el checkbox como en el option cuando hago un summit en la página. Además cómo podría realizarlo mediante el método get, seguiría la misma filosofía. Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
<body
<aside>
    <form name="" action="" method="post" target="">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="cbox1" value="@Request.Form["cbox1"]"> Primer checkbox <br />
                <input type="checkbox" name="cbox2" value="@Request.Form["cbox2"]"> Segundo checkbox <br />
                <input type="checkbox" name="cbox3" value="@Request.Form["cbox3"]"> Tercer checkbox <br />
                <input type="checkbox" name="cbox4" value="@Request.Form["cbox3"]"> Cuarto checkbox

            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
            <p>
                <input type="radio" name="opt1" value="@Request.Form["opt1"]">Primer Option<br>
                <input type="radio" name="opt2" value="@Request.Form["opt2"]">Segundo Option<br>
                <input type="radio" name="pot3" value="@Request.Form["opt3"]"> Tercer Option

            </p>

        </div>

        <span class="sendData">
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar datos">
        </span>

    </form>

</aside>
```

Comment: que tipo de proyecto estas utilizando? porque asp.net no es lo mismo que asp.net mvc. Ademas porque usas el Request, esto no aplica

Comment: creo que ademas deberias aprender algo de html, porque el `radio` deberia tener el mismo `name` para que actuen en conjunto https://tutorialehtml.com/en/html-tutorial-radio-buttons/

Comment: Uso request para intentar dejar seleccionado las opciones del formulario. No sabía que debía declarar el mismo name para que el radio actuara en conjunto. Estoy estudiando progrmación informática así que en ello ando.

Comment: Uso asp.net, había puesto también asp.net - mvc por error.

Answer (score 0):

Con Javascript podría guardar en un LocalStorage la información de todo el formulario en un json, (recordemos que localStorage solamente guarda string)

Por lo demás podría validar si existe información en el localStorage y si la hay que la establezca en el formulario cuando vuelva a cargar la página, es una solución muy pulcra y no necesita enviar los datos por URL (GET)

Tampoco necesitaría incluir liberías adicionales.

Answer (score 0):

Si estas utilizando `asp.net clasico` la forma de acceder y mantener los datos en el submit es usando el `runat="server"` en los controles

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cbox1" runat="server" /> Primer checkbox <br />
<input type="checkbox" id="cbox2" runat="server" /> Segundo checkbox <br />
<input type="checkbox" id="cbox3" runat="server" /> Tercer checkbox <br />
<input type="checkbox" id="cbox4" runat="server" /> Cuarto checkbox
```

Al definirlo por el `id` podrias acceder a este y validar si esta checkeado

```
protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cbox1.Checked)
    {
        //codigo
    }

    if (cbox2.Checked)
    {
        //codigo
    }

    //resto

}
```

Ya que tendras un

[HtmlInputCheckBox](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputcheckbox?view=netframework-4.5)

Para los `radio` es similar

```
<input type="radio" id="opt1" name="opt" runat="server" />Primer Option<br>
<input type="radio" id="opt2" name="opt" runat="server" />Segundo Option<br>
<input type="radio" id="opt3" name="opt" runat="server" /> Tercer Option
```

Nota: Importante que el `name` sea igual para todos los radio que actuen en conjunto

En el evento del boton puedes evaluar cual se selecciono

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     if (opt1.Checked)
        //codigo
     else if (opt2.Checked)
        //codigo
     else if (opt3.Checked)
        //codigo
}
```

Ya que tienes un `html control` del tipo

[HtmlInputRadioButton](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputradiobutton?view=netframework-4.5)

Esto sucede porque pones el `runat=server` en los controles